# Default text into a text field in PowerApps

Tags: powerapps, power-automate, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas

How can I default text into a text box on PowerApps? I've tried setting the default like this:
[image: Default Example]

However, the text box is returning "false".

[image: Text box Example]

I need the text box to have something in it in order for my connected flow to work correctly, however, I don't really want to keep it as a required field for the users so I figured having a space in there would address the issue most easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply keep the space within double quotes as Default text.

> [image]

Btw, I'm getting this error with your snippet. Somehow the resultant boolean is set as value for you.

[image]